# Is there a way how to express this Simulink model as python code correctly?

Tags: python, simulink

I am trying to express simulink model with python code and achieve the plot in simulink but `sympy.integrate` does not do that i'm trying to express. Integrator's (1/s) initial condition is 30.
Integration goes over time.
[Simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brDLF.png)
[Simulink graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSCvs.png)
Code:

```
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Gna = 7800
p = 1292
S = 9.3
h = 2
M = 1
Xa = 0.5
k = 0
Xag = 0
X = np.linspace(0,100,100)

def f(x):
    Ga = ((Gna * x - M )/ Xa) * (1 + k)
    res = (M + Ga * (Xa * (1 + Xag)) - Gna * x)/(p * S * h)
    return res
def F(x):
    return integrate(f,x)
y = []

for i in range(0,101):
    y[i] = F


plt.plot(X, y)
plt.show()
```